# Is there a way to retrieve disk I/O latency time series data from Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, latency, throughput

I want to measure the throughput and latency while transferring data from Google Compute Engine in some region to Google Cloud Storage in another region. I was able to use the following code that consists of "monitoring_v3" and "metric type" set to "compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/max_read_bytes_count" in order to read the timeSeries data of throughput. But I wasn't able to find how to retrieve the disk i/o latency during the data transfer in similar format(timeSeries data). Is there a way how I can get the latency during the data transfer in a timeSeries format?

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
import time

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_id = '########'
project_name = f"projects/{project_id}"
now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds-86400, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 90000), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)
results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/max_read_bytes_count"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)

ret_lst = []
for result in results:
    for point in result.points:
        ret_lst.append(point.value.int64_value / 1048576)

print(ret_lst)
```

Comment: I have updated answer please check if it helped and upvote.

Comment: Young Kim, Is your issue resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution or can you accept or upvote if the existing answer helps

Answer (score 0):

The required information in time series format might not be possible since the only metrics we have are the ones already published.

Google Cloud have some metrics and performance benchmarking that can be achieved in cloud monitoring however its possible in time series [Disk_Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/review-disk-metrics) and [Performance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance)
Please refer to the documentation [Benchmarking](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/benchmarking-pd-performance)FIO however this would be a manual process of correlating the timing and comparing.

As your expecting there is no such feature, still if this feature is needed you can raise a request at [Public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under monitoring section.